# AJAX can't POST to PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms, post

```
FIXED! See bottom for solution.
```

I am having an incredibly hard time with this. I've been at it for weeks now. I am trying to use AJAX to add a new record into mysql. The PHP file works 100% but I can't seem to be able to make AJAX to work with my form which has a POST method of sending data. This is my first time here on StackOverflow btw so take it easy on me. Here is the code:

HTML code:

```
<form name='addform' method='POST' >
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='text' id='cname'></td>
    <td>
        <select id='fuel'>
            <option value='Petrol'>Petrol</option>
            <option value='Diesel'>Diesel</option>
            <option value='Hybrid'>Hybrid</option>
            <option value='LPG'>LPG</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select id='trans'>
            <option value='Automatic'>Automatic</option>
            <option value='Manual'>Manual</option>
            <option value='Semi-Auto'>Semi-Auto</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type='text' id='engine'></td>
    <td><input type='text' id='doors'></td>
    <td><input type='text' id='total'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type='submit' value='Add Car' onclick='addRecord()'></td>
...
```

I have an external .js file to handle Javascript:

```
function addRecord(){
    if (
        document.addform.cname.value == "" 
        || document.addform.fuel.value == "" 
        || >document.addform.trans.value == "" 
        || document.addform.engine.value == "" 
        || document.addform.doors.value == "" 
        || document.addform.total.value == ""
    ) 
    { 
        alert ("Empty >field(s) - Cannot create record"); 
        return;
    }

    var mydata = null;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
    {
        xmlHttpReq2 = new XMLHttpRequest ();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) 
    {
        xmlHttpReq2 = new ActiveXObject ("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    var cname = document.getElementById('cname').value;
    var fuel = document.getElementById('fuel').value;
    var trans = document.getElementById('trans').value;
    var engine = document.getElementById('engine').value;
    var doors = document.getElementById('doors').value;
    var total = document.getElementById('total').value;

    mydata = '?cname='+cname+'&fuel='+fuel+'&trans'+trans+'&engine'+engine+'&doors'+doors+'&total'+total;          

    alert ("To Server (Add New Record):\n\nadd.php" + mydata);

    xmlHttpReq2.open('POST', "add.php" +mydata, true);
    xmlHttpReq2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttpReq2.send(null);
    xmlHttpReq2.onreadystatechange = addRecordCallback;
}
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect ("194.81.104.27", "www", "www");
mysql_select_db ("xyz") or die(mysql_error());

$tot=$_POST[total];
$door=$_POST[doors];
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl 
    (ID, CARNAME, FUELTYPE, TRANSMISSION, ENGINESIZE, DOORS, TOTAL, AVAILABLE)
    VALUES ('$_POST[cname]','$_POST[cname]', '$_POST[fuel]', '$_POST[trans]','$_POST[engine]', $door, $tot, $tot)";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    mysql_close ($link);
?>
```

What happens is I put the info into the form, click the button and the alert tells me that it does indeed get the data from the form. But after that nothing happens. I think that the data is not being sent in the right format to the PHP file for some reason.

Thanks!

```
Solution was:
```

I managed to get it working! Part of the fault was that like @adeneo said I did not have the `onclick='addRecord(); return false;'` in there! Another thing I did was to remove the id of the form, not sure if that did anything at all. I have also attached "mydata" to the .send like so: `xmlHttpReq2.send(mydata);` and finally I had to remove a "?" which was in front of cname in the mydata variable gathering thing. So it was `mydata = '?cname='+cname+...` and I had to remove the `?`. Thanks everyone for all the help!

Comment: What's `add.php` look like?

Comment: Sorry, I did add it but for some reason it wasn't displaying it. Should work now. The PHP file works 100% though. If I for example do <form action=add.php.... then it actually adds stuff into the mysql table but it takes me away to a blank page. But I need to do it through AJAX for my Uni assignment.

Comment: Also a number of your parameters don't have equals signs between name and value (in mydata)

Comment: You said: _"I think that the data is not being sent in the right format to the PHP file for some reason."_ This SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323868/comparison-of-tools-offered-by-different-browsers-for-web-developers mentions the developer/debugging tools that are more-or-less built into the various browsers.  These tools make it **so you don't have to guess** about what is getting sent back to the server.  It makes life much easier.  Sorry if you're aware of these tools already but you did say _"I've been at this for weeks."_

Comment: Are you open to trying jQuery for the AJAX?

Comment: @Robot Woods I fixed that now but still does the same thing.
I am open to jQuery but have no idea what to do and how to do anything with it since I never used it and we haven't been taught to use it which is stupid really.

Comment: Put array keys in quotes (e.g. `$_POST[total]` should be `$_POST['total']`).

Comment: Well, it sure would be easy to just delete your entire database by sending a simple POST request to that script. Once you figure out what the problem is, you should probably start learning PDO.

Comment: @Sverri that is not an issue since my PHP file works if I'm using it alone. I just wanna send the god damn form through AJAX onto php so it can process it. Why is this simple thing so difficult to do?

adeneo I am not interested in learning anything else to do with this. I just want to complete it for my Uni assignment and bury the whole Internet Programming module from my life.

Comment: If this is for a University assignment then you should do your own research and homework!

Comment: @FilipIonita It outputs a notice and should be fixed. Ignoring it is just lazy. And relax.

Comment: @Sverri sorry I am just so pissed off right now. Every time I try it and it doesn't work it makes me wanna smash something. This is my last assignment that I need to complete and it's doing my head in.

Comment: I'll give you a hint! You are doing a POST request, yet you are concentenating all your data to the querystring and sending it as a GET request, and your POST receives null as that is what you are sending. You should `.send(mydata)` when doing POST, as the whole point of a POST request is to be more secure, and the querystring does'nt work with POST requests, or change it to GET.

Comment: @adeneo which would be the querystring? If I change the method to GET my PHP file would be rendered useless since it relies on POST to work. Also, I have a delete.php file and a modify.php file which both use POST and I will need to make them work after I figure this out...

RE: I just tried that and still nothing. The page seems to be refreshing for some reason when I use the button :/

Comment: Here's the script you should be using -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GMuYD/3/) ! And you need to return false somewhere to avoid the default form submit, like `onclick='addRecord(); return false;'`.

Comment: And you have a rogue character -> `|| >document.addform.trans.value == "" ` Thats a syntax error, the `>` before document is invalid

Comment: I managed to get it working! Part of the fault was that like @adeneo said I did not have the `onclick='addRecord(); return false;'` in there! Another thing I did was to remove the id of the form, not sure if that did anything at all. I have also attached "mydata" to the .send like so: `xmlHttpReq2.send(mydata);` and finally I had to remove a "?" which was in front of cname in the mydata variable gathering thing. So it was `mydata = '?cname='+cname+...` and I had to remove the `?`.

Comment: In other words, you used the code in the Fiddle! Here's one with jQuery -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GMuYD/4/)

Comment: @adeneo I didn't even know you had to bring jQuery in with this: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> so yeah it was better that I didn't use jQuery because then I would have had to learn another language syntax by the looks of it and I just don't have the time right now. Thanks so much for all your help buddy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few things wrong.

You are not using the `name` attribute on the `input`/`select` elements. They need to have a `name` in order for them to be sent with the POST request. The `id` attribute has nothing to do with forms (except when using labels; the `for` attribute points to them)

```
<form action="/path/to/php/file.php" method="post" id="addform">
    <div>
        <label for="carname">CName</label>
        <input type="text" name="carname" id="carname">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="fuel">Fuel</label>
        <select id="fuel" name="fuel">
            <option value="Petrol">Petrol</option>
            <option value="Diesel">Diesel</option>
            <option value="Hybrid">Hybrid</option>
            <option value="LPG">LPG</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="transmission">Transmission</label>
        <select id="transmission" name="transmission">
            <option value="Automatic">Automatic</option>
            <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
            <option value="Semi-Auto">Semi-Auto</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="engine">Engine</label>
        <input type="text" id="engine" name="engine">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="doors">Doors</label>
        <input type="text" id="doors" name="doors">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="total">Total</label>
        <input type="text" id="total" name="total">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="submit">Engine</label>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Add Car" onclick="addRecord()">
    </div>
</form>
```

As for the javascript, it is much easier to use jQuery (or a similar library). It abstracts away all the nitty-gritty details and browser differences, and makes your life much easier.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// When the page is done loading...
$(function () {
    // When the form is submitted
    $("form#addform").on("submit", function () {
        // Get the form data and serialize it
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        // Create a POST request
        var post = $.post("/path/to/php/file.php", data);
        // When the request is done show a message
        post.done(function () {
            alert("Form submitted!");
        });
        // If the request fails show another message
        post.fail(function () {
            alert("Error! Form not submitted.");
        });
        // Returning false prevents the form's normal
        // behaviour, i.e. its submission
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Looking at your PHP code it looks like you have just learnt PHP: You are using a deprecated extension (`mysql`); you just use POST variables without bothering with security; and your SQL code looks a little iffy (e.g. what is `AVAILABLE` and why is it set to `$total`?); and finally, string array indices should be quoted.

```
// Database handle
$db = new MySQLi('194.81.104.27', 'www', 'www', 'xyz');

// SQL query with placeholders
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (CARNAME,FUELTYPE,TRANSMISSION,ENGINESIZE,DOORS,TOTAL) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

// Create a statement object
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

// Fill in the placeholders
$stmt->bind_param('ssssii', $carname, $fuel, $transmission, $engine, $doors, $total);

// Set the values
$carname      = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cname', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$fuel         = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fuel', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$transmission = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'transmission', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$engine       = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'engine', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$doors        = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'doors', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$total        = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'total', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

// If the statement was not executed then there was an error
if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found', true, 404);
}
// Done
```

**Note:** I never tested any of the examples. I just wrote them down in my text editor, as needed, so you will probably need to adapt them.

Comment: I just learnt PHP last term lol. I don't intend to secure nothing since I won't be doing any of this in my next year in Uni. This is not my pathway either (I am in Computer Systems Engineering). The AVAILABLE gets the same amount as TOTAL because this is a car renting business and when a batch of cars is added then the total will be equal to available at first. From there I decrement as cars get rented out or increment when they get returned. Delete cars when they get written off etc. Thanks for your input. You seem to know what you're talking about so I'll mark you as the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Your complicating your live since you already use jquery use it for AJAX too.

$.AJAX({
   url: "path to php",
   type: "post",
   data: $("#formID").serialize(),
   });

Send this as data and you will be fine.

Sorry for has spelling, sensed from phone.
Greetings

Ezeky

Comment: Replace your current ajax request with this.

Comment: Also, don't the form inputs need names?

Comment: Ya if I'm correct they serialize on name!! Add into your input tag name="input name"

Comment: Ok I will try.

RE: If I use your code Firebug tells me "addRecord is not defined "

Comment: Also this code should be inside you event trigger . $(document.body).on("submit",  "#formID", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* AJAXCODE */ });

Comment: I have changed the ID's and pathname yes. I will try adding the code inside the trigger, which I assume is the button. So it's going to look like onclick='addRecord($(document.body).on("submit", "#formID", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* AJAXCODE */ });)' right??

Comment: No just add my code don't use the addrecord and change you input tag for the button to a button tag.

Comment: I have managed to get it working but thanks for your input buddy! I would give you reputation but it won't let me :(

Comment: @Ezeky I tried to use this kind of AJAX but in php it shows me error on $_POST['data']. Error "undefined index data". How can i resolve that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the issue is that you're pasting data `"mydata = '?cname='+cname+'&fuel..."` onto the back of the URL like you would if using GET as your transmittal method, but you define POST as the transmittal method, so doing this is unnecessary.

The POST method encapsulates the data for you.Try removing the `+mydata` from this line

```
xmlHttpReq2.open('POST', "add.php" +mydata, true);
```

Also, two more lines down, you're calling a function that's not listed here

```
xmlHttpReq2.onreadystatechange = addRecordCallback;
```

Seeing what that function does would be helpful.